# How to add items in a datatable to a listview?

Tags: c#, sql, listview

I am currently developing a C# Windows Form Application.

Now I am trying to use a SQL Command to retrieve information from the database to fill in the information that I need to have in my Application.

A sample query would be "select * from Location"

In the Location table there would be variables like  locationId, LocationName , districId etc etc.
I used the following code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MasterLocation", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem =new ListViewItem(dr["pk_Location_ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["var_Location_Name"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fk_int_District_ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fk_int_Company_ID"].ToString());
       listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
```

The output is:

[image: like this.]

but it should be like this:

[image: sql output]

Comment: So what kind of output you want?

Comment: Why don't you use [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)? It's exactly what's on the image of how you want it to be and you can also bind a datasource on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have to change some code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.View = View.Details;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionstring");
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from MasterLocation", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dt);

    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];
        ListViewItem listitem = new ListViewItem(dr["pk_Location_ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["var_Location_Name"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fk_int_District_ID"].ToString());
        listitem.SubItems.Add(dr["fk_int_Company_ID"].ToString());
       listView1.Items.Add(listitem);
    }
```

Comment: see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.listviewsubitem.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Added the following code

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void FormView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    sample = new DataTable(); //Sample Data
            sample.Columns.Add("id", typeof(string));
            sample.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
            sample.Rows.Add("1", "apple");
            sample.Rows.Add("2", "acer");
            sample.Rows.Add("3", "alpha");
            sample.Rows.Add("4", "beat");
            sample.Rows.Add("5", "ball");
            sample.Rows.Add("6", "cat");
            sample.Rows.Add("7", "catch");
            sample.Rows.Add("10", "zebra");

            listViewEx1.View = View.Details;
            listViewEx1.Columns.Add("id");
            listViewEx1.Columns.Add("name");
  }



         listViewEx1.Items.Clear();

            listViewEx1.FullRowSelect = true;

            foreach (DataRow row in sample.Rows)
            {
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row["id"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(row["name"].ToString());
                    listViewEx1.Items.Add(item); //Add this row to the ListView
             }
```