# Insert value into a ListView from DataTable C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm working on a project, and I need to display historical price. I alerady made the part to get the data from Yahoo Finance and created a form with a list view to display the data.
There is a button that allow to get the data (they are stocked in a DataTable (This part of the code works fine)) but i canno't manage to put them into the list view, I tried a lot of different methods but I always have the same output, that is the element present in the list view are the object `ListViewItem` but not the value that the object contains, here is a screen shot for you to better understand :
[image: ListView]

and my code is :

```
private async void BtnGetData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable Histo = new DataTable();
            Histo.Clear();
            YahooDataList.Items.Clear();
            foreach (string s in ListCol)
            {
                DataColumn x = new DataColumn();
                x.ColumnName = s;
                x.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
                Histo.Columns.Add(x);
            }
            Symbol = "^FCHI";// Ticker.Text;
            StartDate = "21/02/2021";// DD.Text;
            EndDate = "21/02/2022"; //DF.Text;
                                    //Histo = DataFromYahoo.GetData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate);
            var awaiter = await DataFromYahoo.ReceiveData(Symbol, StartDate, EndDate, Histo);
            if (awaiter ==1)
            {
                for (int j=0; j<Histo.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = Histo.Rows[j];
                    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(dr["Date"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Open"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["High"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Low"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Close"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["AdjClos"].ToString());
                    item.SubItems.Add(dr["Volume"].ToString());
                    YahooDataList.Items.Add(item);
                }
            }
           NbData.Text = Histo.Rows.Count.ToString();
           Histo.Clear();
        }
    }
```

I tried to put the data into the list view following the answer of this post : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584707/how-to-add-items-in-a-datatable-to-a-listview)

I also tried by creating an array :

```
for (int j = 0; j < Histo.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                string[] arr = new string[7];

                arr[0] = Histo.Rows[j][0].ToString();
                arr[1] = Histo.Rows[j][1].ToString();
                arr[2] = Histo.Rows[j][2].ToString();
                arr[3] = Histo.Rows[j][3].ToString();
                arr[4] = Histo.Rows[j][4].ToString();
                arr[5] = Histo.Rows[j][5].ToString();
                arr[6] = Histo.Rows[j][6].ToString();
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(arr);
                YahooDataList.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

But the results are the same.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

EDIT : I don't think there is nothing to do with how I created the list view but still, this is the xaml part for it :

```
<ListView  x:Name ="YahooDataList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="380" Margin="246,25,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="525" >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="75" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Openning" Width="75"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="High" Width="75" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Low" Width="75" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Closing" Width="75" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Clos Adj" Width="75" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Vol" Width="75" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: SubItems is property of the WinForms ListViewItem class. The WPF ListViewItem does not have it. You are apparently adding WinForms ListViewItems to a WPF ListView, which will obviously not work. Search StackOverflow for how to use a WPF ListView with a DataTable: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+listview+datatable

Comment: @Clemens Thank you, I will look into it. I a new to C# and WPF I didn't know that things but I had seen that my List View is an element from System.Windows.Controls and my ListViewItem is from System.Windows.Forms and I was a bit lost.